# How to mount a USB stick in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, automounting, bsd

I am running a FreeNAS (FreeBSD version) on a DELL R310, but when I connect a USB stick it does not automatically get mounted. The same stick does get automatically mounted in CentOS/Fedora.

How do I troubleshoot this and make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a USB kernel module loaded using `kldload` or compile the module into the kernel using the kernel config script in `/usr/src/sys/<type>/conf`. I'm not sure if FreeNAS can be compiled with a USB module, but I'd assume so.

then do `mount -t <filesystem_type> /dev/usb /<some_dir>`